Comparing score distributions
Take two hypothetical measures that I need to compare. I apply them to three individuals, A, B, and C. Let us say Measure 1 assigns scores {A: 1000, B: 999, C: 998}, while Measure 2 assigns scores {A: 100, B: 9, C: 1}, on different scales. Spearman's correlation would yield a result of one, indicating perfect alignment in rankings. However, this assessment overlooks the variability of scores (A and B being much closer for M1 than for M2).
Can you help me understand how to compare the measures, i.e. assess how similar/different they are, (without assuming linearity that I would have with Pearson's correlation) through an index that also considers the differences between scores?

You lost me, because "on different scales" says you cannot compare the variability on one scale to the variability on the other!  Could you help us resolve this conundrum by clarifying what you mean by "similar/different"?

I want to understand how similar two metrics are, i.e. if they convey the same information. They attribute scores on different ranges. What I am interested in is rankings (and for that I use Spearman's correlation), but also differences among scores that produced such rankings (for example how close or distant are the scores internally). I don't know if I was able to clarify, thank you for the comment.
